# PageMethods.MyMethod("sample") goes to the page_load method and not to MyMethod()

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I'm working in Visual Studio 2013 and using a aspx page with a .cs code behind page.  I added the following javascript

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
      function callServerFunction() {
          alert(PageMethods.MyMethod("hello"));
  }
```

(also I tried the various variables to send MyMethod that I saw in examples)

in the code behind page I have the following method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod]
public static string MyMethod(string name)
{
    return "Hello " + name;
}
```

I search the internet and used the suggesting online to modify the asp ScriptManger line in site.Master to include :

EnablePageMethods="true" EnablePartialRendering="true" EnableCdn="true"

In my web.config I added ScriptModule code that was suggested in this page:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1966319.aspx?Asp+net+page+methods+not+working+properly+in+VS+2013

when I run the javascript code the PostMethod just goes to the page_load method in the code behind and displays 'undefined'.  I changed the method name of the javascript and the codebehind and it fails if they are not the same name.  I think that means at least they are seeing each other.

Comment: First thought, did you maybe forget a `runat=server` on a control?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the template has a couple of calls in the Global.asax.cs file like this:

```
// Code that runs on application startup
RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

If it does try commenting them out.